# kubernates replace deployment sometimes doesn't work, rollout error

Tags: kubernetes

We have a kubernetes deployment and on version release we build a new image and run:

```
kubectl replace -f deployment.yml
```

This is always the same deployment file except for the name of the image it uses.
It usually works, but every once in a while it doesn't update the pod,
Running describe on the deployment reveals there's no new replica set:

```
OldReplicaSets: appname-675551529 (1/1 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:  <none>
```

and viewing rollout status Returns the following:

```
Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
error: watch closed before Until timeout
```

Comment: Could be you're hitting https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40224

Comment: Possibly, couldn't figure out what's causing this

Comment: I think if you just want to update the images and do not want to change other resources such as Services then I would try to use **apply** instead of replace. `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40224

Comment: Tried changing to 'apply' instead of 'replace' following your suggestion. Problem didn't reproduce so I think it solves it.
Thanks